# JS Regex Replace Version Number in Filename

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

Starting with the string `css/main.min-1.2.0.css` I'm trying to replace the version number in my HTML dynamically using Gulp for each time we version.

The below regex matches the version number, however I need to match the version number with the string prepended to ensure I update the correct.

`/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)*\b/`

The regex should ideally match this starting string and the file extension, with replacement of the version number `1.0.0`.

`css/main.min-1.0.0.css`

**Edit**

A follow on from this, I'm struggling with why the following fails it seems related to the double quotes!

```js
var string = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/css/main.min-1.0.0.css">';
string.replace(/css\/main[.]min-(?:\d[.]?)+css$/g, 'css/main.min-1.1.1.css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Guedes in the comments the answer is now as below, replacing the whole thing not just the versioning.

```
replace(/css\/main[.]min-(?:\d[.]?)+css$/g, 'css/main.min-' + pkg.version + '.css')
```

**Edit**

Resolved below, example as a gulp task for anyone else to use.

```js
gulp.task('versioned-paths', function(){
    gulp.src(['public/**/*.html', 'public/**/*.php'])
    .pipe(replace(/css\/main\.min-(?:\d\.\d\.\d)\.css/g, 'css/main.min-' + pkg.version + '.css'))
    .pipe(replace(/js\/env\.min-(?:\d\.\d\.\d)\.js/g, 'js/env.min-' + pkg.version + '.js'))
    .pipe(replace(/js\/main\.min-(?:\d\.\d\.\d)\.js/g, 'js/main.min-' + pkg.version + '.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var strings = [
 'css/main.min-1.0.0.css',
 'css/main.min-11.22.33.css',
 'css/main1.min-1.0.0.css'
];

var matchPattern = /^css\/main\.min-\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.css$/;
var replaceString = 'css\/main\.min-2.3.4.css';

strings.forEach(function (string) {
 if (matchPattern.test(string)) {
  console.log(string + " -> matched");
  finalVersion = string.replace(matchPattern, replaceString);
  console.log(finalVersion + " after replace")
 }
 else {
  console.log(string + " -> not matched");
 }
});
```

Comment: Wasn't far off! Thank you, the main bit I forgot to mention was that is was a HTML element rather than just a text string!